# Basecamp document editing lost

Tags: ipad, document, editing, basecamp

I started editing a document on my iPad, and somehow I did something that meant I was returned to the documents list without saving/publishing my changes.

However when I now try and ‘edit’ the document it says "Looks like you already started editing this document", but there is no way to ‘resume’ editing. I just get option to edit anyway (and lose all edits) or cancel, which sends me back to the documents list.

How can I resume my edits?